# Is it wrong to just use `T.s([args])` to just call Celery tasks?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

### The Backstory

In the first part of Celery docs, for ["Calling Tasks"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#example), they describe using `delay()` and `apply_async()`, e.g.:

```
task.delay(arg1, arg2, kwarg1='x', kwarg2='y')

task.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2], kwargs={'kwarg1': 'x', 'kwarg2': 'y'})
```

They go on to explain:

> So delay is clearly convenient, but if you want to set additional execution options you have to use apply_async.

I want the extra options, but passing args/kwargs to `apply_async()` looks ugly to me.

Instead, I've just been using `Task.s()` (signatures), because I can pass in the args in a way that reads like a function *and* just append the call to `apply_async()`.

To explain, this is what most of my tasks look like where I create them:

```
task_id = cool_task.s(arg1, arg2).apply_async()
```

... purely for aesthetics.

### The Question

**Have I overlooked some downside to calling my tasks this way?**

Based on my reading the [Celery Canvas docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#guide-canvas), I know I'm not using signatures for their potential. But am I doing something *wrong*, that may bite me later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with calling tasks using signatures or partials. However, there are cases where you might pass some arguments to a partial and then pass remaining arguments at a later point.

You should be careful in such scenarios. If you use a partial in a chain with incorrect args, the previous task sends its result to partial and which might not be what you want. In such cases, you can use [immutable signatures](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#immutability).